# Best view to display images and html content in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview

*I am working on an application which can read emails. I am using textview / edittext to display the mails. Right now I am able to fetch the email content as string and display it.
But Which is the best view to display emails with html content and images??
Please help me out.
Thank you :)
Edited:
I used webview as suggested by S.O. friends(thanks to  @Andro Selva, @CFlex).
But I am facing a problem, Its displaying the email's body twice! :(
Once as a text/plain and again as a Text/html.
[image: its a screeshot of webview loaded with email message when a blank mail is sent]
I have tried following codes to load webview.

```
webViewBody.loadData(details[3], "text/html", "UTF-8");
//webViewBody.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, details[3] , "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

here details[3] is the email content.
What am i missing here!? :( Please help me out.

EDITED: 
I have Added codes I have Used to get the message contents for displaying email content below.

```
    public void getContent(Message msg)
{
     try
     {
        Object o = msg.getContent();
            if (o instanceof String) 
        {
        if(((String) o).equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
        }
                    else
        {
           messageBody = (String)o+"STRING!!";
        }
       }
       else if (o instanceof Multipart) 
       {
        Multipart mp = (Multipart)o;
            int count3 = mp.getCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < count3-1; j++)
        {
            // Part are numbered starting at 0
            BodyPart b = mp.getBodyPart(j);
            Object o2 = b.getContent();
            if (o2 instanceof String) 
            {
                if(((String) o).equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                }
                                    else
                {
                    messageBody = (String)o2+"MULTIPART!!"; 
                }
            }
        } //End of for
       }
       else if (o instanceof InputStream) 
       {
        //System.out.println("**This is an InputStream message**");
        InputStream is = (InputStream)o;
        // Assumes character content (not binary images)
                    //messageBody = convertStreamToString(is)+"INPUT STREAM!!";
            int c;
                    while ((c = is.read()) != -1) 
                    {
                    messageBody = convertToString(is)+"INPUT STREAM!!";
                System.out.println(messageBody);
                    }
       }
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
    {
    System.out.println("Exception arise at get Content");
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //TODO TEST CODES
    try
    {
        String contentType = msg.getContentType();
        //          System.out.println("Content Type : " + contentType);
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
        int count = mp.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception arise at get Content");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String convertToString(InputStream inputStream)
{
    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    try 
    {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            string.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

The control is always going to "else if (o instanceof InputStream)" condition. so its streaming email always and displaying complete email content. What am I missing here?

Comment: A webview maybe? Has the same effect, but can manage html more effectively than other views

Comment: I have updated my main question, please check and help me out.

Comment: why have you used two load methods? which one did you follow?

Comment: Please debug and see what is in details[3]. Is the content ok or duplicated ? Edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
I tried both the codes separately both resulted in same.(displaying both text/plain and text/html).

I'll log the details[3] and update it in my question soon.

Comment: I have updated my question, please take a look.
The control is always going to  "else if (o instanceof InputStream)"
condition. so its streaming email always and displaying complete email content. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding these lines solved the problem!

```
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me to solve this. :)

Comment: nice! after this how do u choose what content you will display?

Comment: Once these lines are added, then the control will go to corresponding if loops. Check the codes I have posted. If the instance is of type string and so on, you can handle it easily.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to implement a `WebView`, because it can format the html **AND** display images.

AFAIK, A textView with html can format the content but cannot display the images.

**Edit**:
The following should work:

```
webViewBody.loadData(details[3], "text/html", null);
```

Comment: hey, its displays few mails properly, but for most of the mails with images and html content, its giving error saying page could not be loaded :(

Comment: I have updated my main question, please check and help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are displaying all the email content that can be composed by html and plain text content in the same email.
This is caused because this kind of email is multipart content and u need to split-it, you also need to separate attachments and images (embedded)
see if your "details" is not returning a multipart content body.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I guess you are right! I am not able to split things. I'll update my question with the codes I have used, please help me.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question, please take a look.
The control is always going to  "else if (o instanceof InputStream)"
condition. so its streaming email always and displaying complete email content. What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry @AdarshHs, I'm still learning about Android, I speak with knownledge of email format. can u post part of an email content in the "RAW" format as you receive?

Answer (score 2):

The detail gets displayed twice just because of two times you have written:

```
webViewBody.loadData(details[3], "text/html", "UTF-8");
webViewBody.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, details[3] , "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Probable Solution: Use either `loadData()` or `loadDataWithBaseURL()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Oops! I have used only one of them at a time but both resulted in same :(

Comment: I'll comment that line to avoid confusions.